# Typo3 8.7.x / Typoscript: Using fluid parameter in typoscript lib

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

can somebody tell me how to use my passed fluid parameter to my typoscript lib? The following code is not working:

```
lib.slider = CONTENT
lib.slider {
  table = pages
  select {
    where = NOT tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages=0
    pidInList = this
    selectFields.current = 1
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field < lib.slidertitle.select.selectFields
    wrap = |
  }
}

<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.slider" data="tx_pagesaddfields_slidertitle" />
```

Comment: `field < lib.slidertitle.select.selectFields`? or do you mean `field < lib.slider.select.selectFields`? the problem might be: not the resulting content is copied but he configuration. so it's the same as `field.current = 1` that would be field named by the content of the record you selected before. (skip the field and use `current = 1`)

Comment: field < lib.slider.select.selectFields is correct, but it's only a  copy and past error, in my code, it's correct.